# How does negative lookahead with alteration work?

Tags: regex

I am wondering how alteration inside a negative lookahead works, and how negative lookahead works when it is placed ahead of the main expression.

Example:

```
((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)
```

Running that at https://regexr.com, I see these matches:

[image]

Reading the RegEx I expected that it would discard the entire result if it finds a "backslash and a character" *before* zero or more other characters.

However, it only discards the part before (and including) the slash.

Also, does the alteration apply to just the star ahead of it, or to more of the group?

Comment: Which regex implementation are you using?

Comment: `(?!.*\\..*|_next)` matches a position where the following content does not start with `_next` and does not contain a `\ ` that is itself followed by at least *one* character (`..*` is equivalent to `.+`). That is, the two alternatives are `.*\\..*` and `_next`; the engine will try to match them, and if it succeeds it will forfeit the match. The last `.*` matches the rest of the line and therefore this whole regex can only match once per line (excluding the empty match at the end of the line since it is probably an unwanted byproduct).

Comment: Thanks @InSync, so the last .* is irrelevant to the negative lookahead. The negative lookahead only applies to what comes before it, which here is nothing? I am used to seeing the negative lookahead after something, e.g. foo(?!bar)

Comment: Your pattern can be shortened to `(?!.*\\.|_next).*` and will match the whole line if from **the current position** there is not `_next` directly to the right, or an escaped char somewhere to the right.

Comment: No, `.*` is the actual content of the match that you see, and it matches *iff* `(?!...)` asserts that the content that it may match does not match any alternatives.

Comment: @Thefourthbird Thanks, but check this one out: foo_next . There, we have a _next ahead of the current position, but the whole thing is not discarded.

Comment: @Magnus If the assertion is false, the current position moves one to the right, and the assertion (the negative lookahead) is tested again. This happens because the assertion is unanchored.

Comment: @Magnus Using an anchor `^` to assert the start of the string, you could write for example `^(?!.*(?:\\.|_test))`

Comment: I am struggling a bit here, @Thefourthbird. Example: `(?=foo).+` on `barfoo`  <-- The regex engine will start from first character and try the whole regex from there, then, if no match, it will move to next character and do the same. It finds a match once it gets to the position between the `r` and `f`. I understand that the lookaround does not move the engine forward, so both `.+` and `foo` will be matched from that same position. It ends up returning `foo` as the match. I do not understand why, I thought the lookaround was excluded from the resulting match?

Comment: @Magnus Think about it this way, you could write that regex as `foo.*`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I am trying to understand how the algorithm works, so I can apply that understanding to all other lookaround cases. Was my step-by-step explanation of how the engine works correct? Perhaps when it stands in between `s` and `f` and finds the match, it will pick all that is left to the right of the current position, since that is what `.*` dictates. But if that is the case, then it is inconsistent that foo is excluded from the match here: .+(?=foo)

Comment: @Magnus There is a debugger available on regex101 where you can see the steps https://regex101.com/r/8zngBf/1/debugger

Comment: That is not a duplicate at all. The excessive close-voting behavior often seen on SO these days should be tackled, as it is deteriorating the platform's value. I think I got it, by using the debugger. I am happy to add a proper answer if reopened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As has been pointed out, `/((?!.*\\..*|_next).*)/` can be simplified to `/((?!.*\\.+|_next).*)/`. Moreover, there is a match if and only if the match equals the content of capture group 1. The reason for capturing is therefore not apparent. Consequently, I will simply consider the expression without the capture group:

```
/(?!.*\\.+|_next).*/
```

Javascript's regex engine (like virtually all regex engines) maintains a pointer in the string. Initially that pointer is at the beginning of the string. The engine will repeatedly attempt to match the regular expression to the portion of the string that follows the pointer. After each failure the string pointer is advanced one character position.

Suppose the string were

```
"a-b\_nextde"
```

With the pointer at the beginning of the string, `!.*\\.+` matches `"a-b\_"`, so the negative lookahead `(?!.*\\.+|_next)` succeeds, causing the regular expression to fail to obtain a match. The string pointer is therefore advanced one character position so that it is now immediately before the hyphen. Think of the pointer as now being *between* `"a"` and `"-"`.

`!.*\\.+` now matches "`-b\_"` so the regular expression fails to match again. The pointer is therefore moved to precede `"b"`.

`!.*\\.+` matches `"b\_"`, so this match fails. The pointer is then moved to precede `"\"`.

Here `"\_"` is matched by `!.*\\.+`, so the match fails yet again and the pointer is moved to precede `"_"`.

At this location `!.*\\.+` fails to match `"_nextde"`, but the second part of the alternation, `_next`, does match, so again the negative lookahead succeeds, causing the match to fail. The pointer is therefore moved to precede `"n"`.

Here neither `!.*\\.+` nor `"_next"` match `"nextde"` so the negative lookahead fails (to prevent a match), allowing `.*` to match `"nextde"`.

We are not quite finished, however. The string pointer is now just after the `"e"` at the end of the string. There neither `!.*\\.+` nor `"_next"` match an empty string so the negative lookahead fails, allowing `.*` to match an empty string. The pointer is then moved to the end of the string, terminating the engine's search.

We are now finished, having matched `"nextde"` and an empty string.

Note that if the regex had ended with `.+` (instead of `.*`) we would only have the single match, `"nextde"`.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/5y5bgK/1)

Comment: Thanks for an excellent explanation. I played around with the debugger and noticed that `.*(?!.*\\.+|_next).*` is marginally harder to understand. It starts at position 0 of `a-b\_nextde` as you say, then it matches .* to the full string, thus leaving the pointer on the last position (after `e`). Somehow the debugger starts backtracking from there, which I think is because the engine needs to try all permutations of the regex until it finds a full match (or not). Though I am not entirely sure about this. If you have time, an explanation of that case would no doubt be helpful to future visitors

Comment: Actually, `.*(?!.*\\.+|_next).*` is easier to understand. Consider first `.*(?!.*\\.+|_next)`. I used that regex with the same string, but with the PCRE regex engine, [here](https://regex101.com/r/T0Xu2I/1). The PCRE engine will give the same results but, unlike the JS engine, the debugger can be used. If you invoke the debugger you will see that it first executes `.*`, which of course matches the entire string, and moves the string pointer just past the last character. It then evaluates `(?!.*\\.+|_next)` against an empty string, which of course fails (to disqualify the match)...

Comment: ...`.*` then matches an empty string and finds that `(?!.*\\.+|_next)` again fails. At this point `.*` fails as we have reached the end of the string. We therefore have two matches, the entire string and an empty string. (If the regex had begun with `.+`, rather than `.*`, we would have a single match, the entire string.)  `.*(?!.*\\.+|_next).*` produces the same result since the second `.*` is not executed until the end of the string has been reached.

Comment: It may be that you were thinking that `.*(?!.*\\.+|_next)` behaved something like `(?:.(?!.*\\.+|_next))*`, but that is not the case. Note that I added three paragraphs to the end of my answer.

Comment: Thanks a million. It does not go back to test the lookahead at `a-b\_nextd`, `a-b\_next`, `a-b\_nex`, `a-b\_ne`, etc. then, as I originally thought. I could have sworn the debugger did that on me the first time I tried, but following your link it no longer behaves that way :)

Comment: Ah, I now see what I tried when I got the backtracking behavior. I did `.*(?=.*\\.+|_next)`, i.e. a positive, not a negative, lookahead. It gets to the end as expexted, after matching `.*`. Then, it tests the empty string as you say. From there, a negative and a positive lookahead differs. The negative one finishes, and does not backtrack. The positive lookahead, on the other hand, checks the lookahead from all positions, backtracking from the rear.